# Images are loaded sequentially

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have this come:

```
<View>
    <Image source={{ uri: favicon }} />
    <Image
      style={iconStyles}
      source={require("./a-local-image.png")}
    />
</View>
```

My problem is that the second image, which is local is not shown until the first image loads. How can I make load the second one first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to place the second `Image` above the first one so the renderer will render it first, then styling both `Images` into their desired positions. You might be able to do this by setting `flexDirection:row-reverse` or `flexDirection:column-reverse` on the parent `View`.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure your second image its being loaded because its point to .js file as source.

Or just explain why image source its point to .js

**source={require("./a-local-image.js")}**